# persistence in SQL and Nosql

Tags: sql, nosql

How to persist an an attribute of an object X in sql and the other attributes of the same object in a base Nosql? If I take this example :

```
@Entity
public class Personne { 
    private String nom; 
    private Analyse analyse;
}
@NoSql
public class Analyse {
    private int id;
    private type;
}
```

I'm wondering about the configuration in the persistance.xml I should put the two persistence units but normally the container glassfish can not consider consider the two persistence units , the container normally support just  one unit. What should I do?

Comment: There is no much details in your question but you can easily insert in both by using the technology you want.

Comment: Rogério Carvalho, look my last edit plz